# How to check all pd.DataFrame for regular expression?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I need check few dataframes.
If df do not contain regular expression, I need to clear it.
I don't know column there it should be.

How to check all DataFrame for containing regular expression?
Without loop to check column?

This is how I do it now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import codecs

# read file
folder = 'folder_path'
file = 'file_name.html'
html_df = pd.read_html(folder + '/' + file)

# check dataframes
html_match = re.compile(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')
# add DF number with html_match
df_check = []
for i, df in enumerate(html_df):
    for col in df.columns:
        try:
            if len(df[df[col].str.contains(html_match) == True]) != 0:
                df_check.append(i)
            else:
                continue
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

Comment: Please provide a clear and reproducible example of your input. "few dataframes"/contain regular expression"/"clear it" are not clear enough

Comment: I've just add exaple how I solve this problem now.

Comment: does this work? what doesn't it do?

Comment: Yes, it's work. But I'm interesting is there any way to check dataframe, not any column in dataframe. And do I need make it this way?

Comment: @JohnDoe, can you share a link to your input `file_name.html` ?

Comment: I can't, it contains confidential information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear, but if I understand correctly you want to filter the output of [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) (which is a list of DataFrames) to only keep those that contain a specific match:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

html_df = [pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C_TOM'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]),
           pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]),
           pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B_TOD', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]),
          ]

out = []

for d in html_df:
    if np.any(d.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(r'_TOM$|_TOD$'))):
        out.append(d)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
out = [d for d in html_df
       if np.any(d.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')))]
```

Output:

```
[   0  1      2
 0  A  B  C_TOM
 1  D  E      F,
    0      1  2
 0  A  B_TOD  C
 1  D      E  F]
```

Comment: Note that if you have non-object columns, you wan filter them out using `d.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')` in place of `d.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to iterate over the whole dataframe.
You can apply the `str.contains` function to all columns and then chech for the rows that have any columns matching:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import codecs

# read file
folder = 'folder_path'
file = 'file_name.html'
html_df = pd.read_html(folder + '/' + file)

# check dataframes
html_match = re.compile(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')
matching_rows = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(html_match)).any(axis=1)

# convert to regular list
df_check = np.nonzero(matching_rows)[0].tolist()
```

## Update

To check only for string columns:

```py
...

# check dataframes
html_match = re.compile(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')

def matches(s):
    try:
        return s.str.contains(html_match)
    except AttributeError:
        return pd.Series(False, index=s.index)

matching_rows = df.apply(matches).any(axis=1)

# convert to regular list
df_check = np.nonzero(matching_rows)[0].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks! But  this code need one correct, because dataframe could contain not string columns.

Comment: Yep you are right, I will update my answer